# Azure SDK in scala

Tags: scala, azure, sbt

I have imported several of the sdk components to my sbt file. In intelliJ all compiles fine, and when I try to compile in sbt I get an error of

> object microsoft is not a member of package com`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-mgmt-resources" % "0.8.3",
  "com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-management"     % "0.8.0",
  "com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-storage"        % "4.0.0",
  "com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-mgmt-utility"   % "0.8.3"   exclude ("commons-codec", "commons-codec"),
  "com.sun.jersey"      % "jersey-core"          % "1.19"
)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like much detail to work with. Maybe edit your question with more info, such as which SDK version you tried to install, along with anything else that might help diagnose the error.

Comment: sorry, added the dep in the sbt file

Comment: Were you able to read/write/update azure blob storage files with Scala?

Answer (score 0):

I Had to do sbt reload in order to refresh the dependencies